How to return unique, ordered data in Excel?
Last year I asked the following question. The formula has been working great. But I've been asked to provide some additional information that I can't quite figure out how to add.
My input data now looks like this:



Name
Sex
Total
Event
Team




Taylor
f
268
Event1
Team A


Taylor
f
252
Event 2
Team A


Halle
f
251
Event 1
Team C


Christian
m
410
Event 2
Team D


abc
m
216
Event 3
Team E



I need to now also include the event and the team associated with the person and their total. I've tried to use similar functions within the LET() but to no avail. I figure I need to use either INDEX/MATCH or XLOOKUP with multiple criteria, but I can't figure out how to structure the formula.
Thanks
